# For some reason `node-sass` isn't working

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to install the `node-sass` npm module on macOS 10.12. I installed npm fine with `brew install node` (although I needed to `sudo chown` some directories), and `npm install -g node-sass` works fine and installs it perfectly fine. However, when I run `node-sass` after that it doesn't work. It just says `-bash: node-sass: command not found`. The command `which npm` returns `/usr/local/bin/npm` if that helps.

Installing `node-sass` locally with just `npm install node-sass` without the global flag (`-g`), `cd`-ing into `./node-modules/node-sass/bin/` and then running `./node-sass` works, but I'd like it to run globally because an Atom package I'd like to use (`sass-autocompile`) requires it to run globally.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem and I'm posting this answer for anyone else that may have the same problem.

First, check the path prefix of `npm`. You can check the path prefix with `npm config get prefix`.

My path prefix was actually `/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.0/libexec/npm` instead of `/usr/local`.

Change this to `/usr/local/` with `npm config set prefix /usr/local`. Also use `sudo chown $USER /usr/local/ && sudo chown $USER /usr/local/bin` to change ownership of those directories if your current user doesn't already own them.

Now you can run `npm install -g node-sass` and after installation, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX, path to 'node-sass' command is required.

Did you install the package globally (npm install -g node-sass) or locally? If locally, the CLI tool can be called as ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass

When it's installed globally, you need to have /usr/local/bin in your $PATH environment variable. Or call it with a full path: /usr/local/bin/node-sass -o ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, that returns `-bash: /usr/local/bin/node-sass: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I ahve change answer try again plz

Comment: What does this return: ls -al /usr/local/bin/node-sass?

Comment: I installed it globally with the `-g` flag (thanks for reminding me of this; I added it to the answer). `ls -al /usr/local/bin/node-sass` returns `ls: /usr/local/bin/node-sass: No such file or directory`. Another thing: When I install it locally (i.e. without the `-g` flag and `cd` into `./node-modules/node-sass/bin/`, I can run `./node-sass`. I just can't run it globally with `node-sass` or even `/usr/local/bin/node-sass`, which I'd like to do because an Atom package I want to use requires that.

Comment: you can compile sass on Mac OSX (Using "sass-autocompile" package).

Comment: Yeah, that's the package I'm trying to use. However, it needs node and the `node-sass` module to work.